# How to install POV-Ray

Tags: x86

I've [Downloaded povlinux-3.6.tgz binary distribution](http://www.povray.org/download/linux.php) and after `./install` I got the message

> POV-Ray 3.6 installation
>
> This machine does not seem to be a Linux PC. This version of POV-Ray
>   only runs on x86 Linux machines. You can obtain a version appropriate
>   for your architecture on http://www.povray.org/
>
> If you want to force an installation you can use
>
> `install -no-arch-check`

But `uname -a` shows

> Linux vaio 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

So is my pc a `x86` machine? How to install POV? Should I do `install -no-arch-check`?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to install from source. See [eg](http://news.povray.org/povray.unix/thread/%3Cweb.4c0138267b313a54fe8f48170@news.povray.org%3E/)

Comment: Thanks. `apt-get` solved the problem.